# Cannot get aurelia-dragula plugin to work

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to check out the [aurelia-dragula plugin](https://github.com/michaelmalonenz/aurelia-dragula) to see if it meets my needs, but when I attempt to drag what should be a draggable element, nothing happens. I have even tried the [example](https://github.com/michaelmalonenz/aurelia-dragula-example) and it doesn't work either.

For my custom test, I created a new project using the aurelia cli and npm installed aurelia-dragula 1.2.6. Here's my code:

**aurelia.json**

```
{
    "name": "aurelia-dragula",
    "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dragula/dist/amd",
    "main": "dragula"
}
```

**main.js**

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources')
    .plugin('aurelia-dragula');
```

The browser log shows the plugin as being loaded, so I assume all is well with the above.

I used the sample html and javascript from the documentation for the custom-element approach, like so:

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <dragula-and-drop drop-fn.call="itemDropped(item, target, source, sibling, itemVM, siblingVM)"></dragula-and-drop>
    <div class="drag-source drop-target">
      <div repeat.for="thing of things">
          <p style="background-color: red; color: white; width: 200px;"">${thing}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
    constructor() {
      this.things = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
    }

    itemDropped(item, target, source, sibling, itemVM, siblingVM) {
      //do things in here
    }
}
```

Comment: I've download, install, build and run example from github -- it's work fine in Firefox. Check your browser for errors. In firefox you can press <CTRL+SHIFT+J> for open javascript console.

Comment: @JayDi There were no errors in the browser console. I downloaded the example from github and tried again. This time it worked. No idea why. I still can't get it to work in my own test project using Aurelia CLI.

Comment: There are some resources in dragula: try to add that line in dragula dependency in aurelia.json: "resources": ["dragula.css"]

Comment: @JayDi That didn't work either.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I don't recommend dragula. Try aurelia-interactjs instead. https://github.com/eriklieben/aurelia-interactjs

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis That's what I am doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget the import?

```
import {Dragula} from 'aurelia-dragula';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your aurelia.json file.
Try this:

```
{
   "name": "aurelia-dragula",
   "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dragula/dist/amd",
   "main": "index"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's certainly a bit late, but if anyone has the same problem, here is the correct aurelia.json setting for aurelia-dragula :

```
{
    "name": "aurelia-dragula",
    "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dragula/dist/amd",
    "main": "index",
    "resources": [
        "*.js",
        "*.html",
        "*.css"
    ]
}
```

The problem is that resources were not loaded. Actually I don't know why because I thought that all the plugin content (corresponding to the `path`) would be bundled and loaded, but it seems that it is not the case.

That being said, aurelia-cli has improved and now proposes an `import` command, which is great. You just `npm install` your library and then `au import` it, which fills the `aurelia.json` file. However, you sometimes need to make some manual adjustments, as this one ; I wonder why this import command does not fill properly the `aurelia.json` part.

Hope this helps ! :-)